# How to find Customer Entities logical name from Guid in Microsoft CRM

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm

In CRM I am trying to automate the process of creating a new email from a previous email in the chain. This email has to go to the customer of the case, who could be either an `account` or a `contact`.

I can retrieve the Guid of the contact/account but I dont know how to retrieve the logical name.

This is what I have so far:

```
OrganizationServiceProxy service = CRMCentralCRMServiceInstance;

Guid customerId = GetCustomerIdFromCase(caseId);

Entity email = new Entity("email");

Entity activityPartyTo = new Entity("activityparty");

//"account" is a guess, it could be "contact"
EntityReference customerReferenceTo = new EntityReference("account", customerId); 

activityPartyTo["partyid"] = customerReferenceTo;
EntityCollection toEntityCollection = new EntityCollection();
toEntityCollection.Entities.Add(activityPartyTo);
email["to"] = toEntityCollection;
.
.
.
newEmailId = service.Create(email);



public Guid GetCustomerIdFromCase(Guid caseId) {
    Guid customerId = Guid.Empty;
    List<CRMCase> caseList = GetCRMCasesById(caseId);

    if (caseList.Count > 0)
    {
        CRMCase cmcCase = caseList.First();
        customerId = cmcCase.CustomerId;
    }

    return (customerId);
}

public List<CRMCase> GetCRMCasesById(Guid caseId)
    {
        List<CRMCase> crmCases = new List<CRMCase>();

        try
        {
            OrganizationServiceProxy service = CRMCentralCRMServiceInstance;

            ConditionExpression condition1 = new ConditionExpression();
            ConditionExpression condition2 = new ConditionExpression();

            condition1.AttributeName = "incidentid";
            condition1.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
            condition1.Values.Add(caseId.ToString("N"));

            condition2.AttributeName = "statecode";
            condition2.Operator = ConditionOperator.In;
            condition2.Values.Add("Active");
            condition2.Values.Add("Resolved");

            FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();

            filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
            filter.Conditions.Add(condition1);
            filter.Conditions.Add(condition2);

            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();

            query.EntityName = "incident";
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
            query.Criteria = filter;


            RetrieveAttributeRequest retrieveAttributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
            retrieveAttributeRequest.EntityLogicalName = "incident";
            retrieveAttributeRequest.LogicalName = "statuscode";
            retrieveAttributeRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;

            RetrieveAttributeResponse retrieveAttributeResponse = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)service.Execute(retrieveAttributeRequest);
            StatusAttributeMetadata statusCodeAttribute = (StatusAttributeMetadata)retrieveAttributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;


            retrieveAttributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
            retrieveAttributeRequest.EntityLogicalName = "incident";
            retrieveAttributeRequest.LogicalName = "prioritycode";
            retrieveAttributeRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;

            retrieveAttributeResponse = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)service.Execute(retrieveAttributeRequest);
            PicklistAttributeMetadata priorityCodeAttribute = (PicklistAttributeMetadata)retrieveAttributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;


            retrieveAttributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest();
            retrieveAttributeRequest.EntityLogicalName = "incident";
            retrieveAttributeRequest.LogicalName = "statecode";
            retrieveAttributeRequest.RetrieveAsIfPublished = true;

            retrieveAttributeResponse = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)service.Execute(retrieveAttributeRequest);
            StateAttributeMetadata stateCodeAttribute = (StateAttributeMetadata)retrieveAttributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;


            EntityCollection casesColl = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            foreach (Entity entity in casesColl.Entities)
            {
                Entity incidentCRMCase = entity;
                CRMCase cRMCase = GetCRMCaseFromIncidentCase(incidentCRMCase, statusCodeAttribute.OptionSet.Options, stateCodeAttribute.OptionSet.Options, priorityCodeAttribute.OptionSet.Options);
                crmCases.Add(cRMCase);
            }
        }
        catch (SoapException se)
        {
            string action = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name + " :: " + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            string message = "Unexpected error in action: " + action
                                + Environment.NewLine + se.Message
                                + Environment.NewLine + se.Detail.InnerText;

            throw new Exception(message);
        }

        return (crmCases);
    }
```

I found [this](http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/04/retrieve-entity-logical-name-from.html) brute force method but I would rather find a cleaner way if there is.

Comment: Could you please add GetCustomerIdFromCase method to your question. I can help you to fix it to return EntityReference instead of Guid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Really complicated code. Try to use something like following:

```
private EntityReference GetCustomerFromCase(Guid caseId)
{
    Entity Case = CRMCentralCRMServiceInstance.Retrieve("incident", caseId, new ColumnSet("customerid"));
    return Case.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("customerid");
}
```